# More groups in common than total groups?

Tags: steam

I got a friend request on Steam so I checked out the user's profile to see the groups and friends we have in common only to find out that he has 3 groups and we have 4 groups in common (sorry about the Finnish screenshot):

[image: Groups 3. You have 4 groups in common]

How is it possible that we have more groups in common than he has in total?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the [total groups](http://steamcommunity.com/id/3ventic/groups/) list does not include official game groups, but the [groups in common](http://steamcommunity.com/id/3ventic/groupscommon/) does. The difference in this case was the official Payday 2 group, which was excluded from the total groups count.